# Android Start an activity in preExecute and finish it in postExecute during running Async Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to specify an activity to be the loading activity for my app for some **async Tasks** .

it will be launched during in `preExecute` and will be finished in `postExecute` how to do that ?

```
           @Override
            protected  void onPreExecute()
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(SearchActivity.this,LoadingActivity.class));
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result)
            {
               // i want to finish loading activity here.
            }
```

Comment: you can do it by loader dialog or something. No need to doing it by Activity..!!

Comment: this is the requirements of my task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just not how Android works.

There is always one Activity active at a time, and when you start an AsyncTask, you do so in the context of the current Activity.

So, while you technically could start an activity from the AsyncTask, it's parent context (the Activity that started the AsyncTask) would become inactive. The AsyncTask would continue to run (this is actually a big problem with AsyncTasks), but would likely crash - and even if not, the behavior would be undefined.

Shubham Nandanwar's answer looks like it should work, but is not the correct way to approach this. You should reconsider what you are trying to do in the context of the way that Activities and their lifecycles are supposed to work.

I'd suggest simply launching the Activity that you desire, and then use an AsyncTask in that activity to do whatever work needs to be done, and finish the activity from the activity itself when the work is done.

Better yet, find a better way to do background processing (e.g. RxJava), and do away with the AsyncTask.

Comment: in my case i can't do my logic in the "loading activity" and finish the activity from the activity itself my tasks are about loading data from API and treat with the result returned from onPostExecute in different ways so if i used your approach i will create "loading" activity for each task. i just want to make this "loading activity" just as "loading dialog"

Comment: agree with GreyBeardedGeek.. @AsmaaRashad this is not possible in Android..!!

Comment: There's actually no reason that which tasks you execute need to be constrained by which activity is active. It should all be done on a background thread. I'm not sure what you intend to do from onPostExecute, but whatever it is will happen on the UI thread anyway, so just move that decision from the AsyncTask, and put it in the parent Activity instead.

You won't need a separate Activity for each task.
Again, you should read up on how Contexts work, and how AsyncTasks work, and use them as intended, rather than trying to do things in a way that is not supported.